# Java Map Value Comparator, sort while inserting

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, insert

I would like to insert items into a HashMap, TreeMap or SortedMap (you may suggest some other api) using a value Comparator.

I Have read many posts including this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java), most of the posts suggest to re-insert the HashMap into a SortedMap with a value Comparator after all items have been inserted.

I am not interested to re-insert all values again. Isn't there an option or a Map similar data structure which supports the activation of a value Comparator after each insert?

If there is a duplicate issue i would appreciate a link (I have done some search, although I may have missed some)

**Again, I am interested in adding a value to some kind of ordered Map so that all items will be ordered by the value and not the key, after each single insert.**

The value in the Map entry is actually a complex Object with some getters, and I want to sort only by a specific getter on the value object.

Comment: You could insert the items into a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and give the TreeMap the required comparator in its constructor? Exactly as shown in the question you've already linked to.

Comment: why don't you like the answer you've by yourself mentioned in the question? You need an ordered map - use TreeMap. You need to compare by specific field in the value - use valuecomparator as was suggested, the implementation will slightly change but the ratio is still the same.

Comment: @MarkBramnik those maps pass in keys not values, right?

Comment: @DNA : TreeMap doesn't take as input a value comperator, but only a key comperator

Comment: @Mark Bramnik: please see the solution again, it requeires to re-insert all items, `sorted_map.putAll(map);` the TreeMap but itself can't recieve a value comperator

Comment: @Michael - the linked example clearly shows a TreeMap being initialised with a Comparator that sorts on values. I'd call that a "value comparator". However, do read the comments about the various problems with that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have though of a some workaround , it is not perfect and and will use some more memory, but it rather simple.

I may extend the key of the Map to also hold the value returned by the getter of the Value object, Then i will extend the key Comparator to sort by the right tuple of the key.

**UPDATE**

Worked as a charm with a very good performance.

Comment: If the key holds the value, how do you retrieve values from the map? You need to know the sorting value in order to get the object value?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is [`org.apache.commons.collections.bidimap.TreeBidiMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs-COLLECTIONS_3_1/org/apache/commons/collections/bidimap/TreeBidiMap.html)

> Red-Black tree-based implementation of BidiMap where all objects added implement the Comparable interface.
>
> This class guarantees that the map will be in both ascending key order and ascending value order, sorted according to the natural order for the key's and value's classes.

Comment: Thanks for your solution , i would prefer to not use any external libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Maps are all about going from a key to a value. Guava has a concept for [bidirectional mappings](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) but you don't really care about going from value to key but rather exposing a sorted iteration of values. What I recommend is a custom container that would house both a HashMap and a [Priority Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

So, extend the the Map, Collection, and Iterable interfaces and on add insert into both the HashMap and Priority Queue. When you iterate, iterate over the queue, when you search/get go to the map.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar, and wasn't able to use the `TreeBidiMap` because it requires the Map's Keys to implement the Comparable interface.

So i wrote my own minimalistic `ValueTreeMap`:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class ValueTreeMap<K, V extends Comparable<V>> implements Iterable<V> {
    private TreeSet<V> tree = new TreeSet<V>();
    private HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();

    public void put(K key, V value){
        V oldValue = map.get(key);
        if(oldValue != null){
            tree.remove(oldValue);
        }
        tree.add(value);
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public V get(K key){
        return map.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<V> iterator() {
        return tree.iterator();
    }

}
```

Comment: I extended your solution to build a class that implements `Map`: [github](https://github.com/jegesh/cn1-object-cacher/blob/master/src/net/gesher/cn1/caching/ValueTreeMap.java)